# How much do people charge for EE R&D work?

Tags: pcb-design, software, cost, research

My software startup is considering a project for a client that has a significant hardware component: a custom device with GSM, GPS and CAN connectivity for use inside a vehicle. We'll design the board ourselves (we have hardware experience), and we'll have to research CAN codes for locking/unlocking car doors, produced prototypes and write the firmware from scratch.

We'll soon have to negotiate a price for the R&D (calculating the per-device cost will be easier), but we don't know what is typical in the industry. How much should work like that cost? I'm just looking for a ballpark figure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about business than EE.

Comment: It's not a general business question. It's *specifically* about how much EE work costs. Only people in the EE field would know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I've seen I think $100-200 is a typical rough ball park hourly rate for small companies. This is for time and material type contracts. Fixed bid should be 30% or so higher.